# android studio error Unsupported class file major version 28773

Tags: android, gradle

Getting this error when i try to reload a project. it is a recent simple project made just 2 days ago. I am totally at loss.

I couldnt find a solution for the exact error with no:  28773 . Some other solutions i found in stackoverflow has number 61, 64 etc which i tried but didnt solve the issue.

The idea.log shows

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: androidx/fragment/lint/FragmentIssueRegistry has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly caused the error. I found `.\gradle build` and `.\gradle installDebug` working but Gradle sync in IDE doesn't work !!!

Anyways I installed a newer version of Android Studio (my previous version was Electric Eel, I now installed Giraffe) and the problem no longer exists.

If any of you knows the proper solution (instead of intalling new version) please post.